# It's possible to give a variable value from file.php?value?

Tags: php

I have a arduino and I want to send the data to Raspberry Pi from the Wifi Network, but with that I need a method to write the data from arduino to the Raspberry Pi SQL database.

I was thiking to make like that, http://raspberry_ip/file.php?value

The value was what I want to write in the SQL Database, or more easy, give the "value" to a variable $temperature.

It's possible to make with PHP?

Comment: It's possible. Have you tried anything?

Comment: No nothing, I can't know how to do!